# UITableView multiple actions

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, uitableviewrowaction

In the editing mode of UITableView, I need three things, the first two are easy to get using UITableView delegate methods:

1. Delete (- in red) button on the left of the row,
2. Reorder (three bars) row button on the right of the row,
3. A custom defined action (with title & background color) appearing on the left side of reorder (three bars) button.

How is it possible to get these three actions together?

Answer (score 1):

Hi yes it is possible to make or add your own custom action by implementing the tableView delegate

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

 let archiveAction:UITableViewRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "                      ") { (rowAct, index) in

   }

 let deleteAction:UITableViewRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "                     ") { (rowAct, index) in

}

   let archiveImg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "archive_btn"))
        archiveImg.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        archiveAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage:archiveImg.image!)

        let deleteImg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "delete_btn"))
        deleteImg.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage:deleteImg.image!)

        return [deleteAction,archiveAction]
}
```

Comment: I want standard iOS buttons, not my own.

Comment: I think its better if you create what you exactly want into the tableview cell xib and just hide show the view where you want on editing according to the cell index.